# Sorting PHP array results via associated object value

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm new to the PHP world and am trying to sort the results of an array by a value from an associated object. Not sure how I include the associated object in the initial array. It's for a Membership Directory list I built that works as needed except for I cannot sort the list. Calling a Memberships object to retrieve all active members, and than need to use the member ID to tie to Users object and leverage Last Name field to sort by. I'm able to pull this info as I loop through the array, but can't figure out how to sort by this field before the loop.

```
// Get array of Active RCP members
$memberships = rcp_get_memberships( array('status' => 'active') );  

// For each active member, write a row with Name, custom meta fields, Email
foreach ($memberships as $value) {
    $customer = $value->get_customer(); 
    $user_id = $customer->get_user_id();

    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    $Fname = $user_info->first_name;    
    $Lname = $user_info->last_name;
    $School = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'rcp_school', true );
    $Role = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'rcp_role', true );
    $Gender = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'rcp_gender', true );
    $Email = $user_info->user_email;
    $Phone = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'rcp_phone', true );

    $message .= '<tr><td class="directory-cell">' . $Lname . ', ' . $Fname . '</td><td class="directory-cell">' . $School . '</td><td class="directory-cell">' . $Role . '</td><td class="directory-cell">' . $Gender . '</td><td class="directory-cell">' . $Email . '</td><td class="directory-cell">' . $Phone . '</td></tr>';}  

// Close table after all active members are looped through  
$message .= '</table>'; 

// Return output for shortcode
return $message;
```

Comment: show us `rcp_get_memberships()`

Comment: You're going to have to make a second loop... since you need to choose how you're going to sort your array. If it's by name, that's apparently not part of the `$membership` array? So you'd need to loop through the `$value` make a new array with what you want to sort by, then sort by that and get your output.

Answer (score 0):

Loops are free, you can use more than one.

You should create an array that contains objects composed of both the customer and user records (it looks like you don't need the membership record after you get the customer data from it). You can then sort that array by the name, and iterate through the sorted array to generate your output.

```php
// Get array of Active RCP members
$memberships = rcp_get_memberships(['status' => 'active']);

/**
 * We're going to build an array of objects that each contain a customer and the related user record.
 */
$compObjBuffer = [];

// Populate the buffer
foreach ($memberships as $value)
{
    $customer  = $value->get_customer();
    $user_id   = $customer->get_user_id();
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    
    $compObj             = new stdClass();
    $compObj->customer   = $customer;
    $compObj->user       = $user_info;
    
    $compObjBuffer[] = $compObj;
}

// Sort the buffer by user last name
usort($compObjBuffer, function($a, $b)
{
    return $a->user->last_name <=> $b->user->last_name;
});

// Iterate through the sorted buffer and generat the output
foreach ($compObj as $currCompObj)
{
    $Fname  = $currCompObj->user->first_name;
    $Lname  = $currCompObj->user->last_name;
    $Email  = $currCompObj->user->user_email;
    
    $School = get_user_meta($currCompObj->customer->get_user_id(), 'rcp_school', true);
    $Role   = get_user_meta($currCompObj->customer->get_user_id(), 'rcp_role', true);
    $Gender = get_user_meta($currCompObj->customer->get_user_id(), 'rcp_gender', true);
    $Phone  = get_user_meta($currCompObj->customer->get_user_id(), 'rcp_phone', true);
    
    $message .= '<tr><td class="directory-cell">' . $Lname . ', ' . $Fname . '</td><td class="directory-cell">' . $School . '</td><td class="directory-cell">' . $Role . '</td><td class="directory-cell">' . $Gender . '</td><td class="directory-cell">' . $Email . '</td><td class="directory-cell">' . $Phone . '</td></tr>';
}

// Close table after all active members are looped through
$message .= '</table>';

// Return output for shortcode
return $message;
```

All that being said, you should probably look into some ways to optimize this. If you're having to make DB queries in get_customer and get_user_data, this is pretty inefficient. You could probably solve that AND your sorting in the DB with some refactoring.